# Parallel Task advice

Tags: c#-4.0

I am trying to use the parallel task library to kick off a number of tasks like this:

```
var workTasks = _schedules.Where(x => x.Task.Enabled);   
_tasks = new Task[workTasks.Count()];    
_cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();       
_cancellationTokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();    

int i = 0;    
foreach (var schedule in _schedules.Where(x => x.Task.Enabled))
{
    _log.InfoFormat("Reading task information for task {0}", schedule.Task.Name);    
    if(!schedule.Task.Enabled)
    {
        _log.InfoFormat("task {0} disabled.", schedule.Task.Name);    
        i++;    
        continue;   
    }

    schedule.Task.ServiceStarted = true;    
    _tasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            schedule.Task.Run()
        , _cancellationTokenSource.Token);                        
    i++;    
    _log.InfoFormat("task {0} has been added to the worker threads and has been started.", schedule.Task.Name);
}
```

I want these tasks to sleep and then wake up every 5 minutes and do their stuff, at the moment I am using Thread.Sleep in the Schedule object whose Run method is the Action that is passed into StartNew as an argument like this:

```
_tasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        schedule.Task.Run()
    , _cancellationTokenSource.Token);
```

I read somewhere that Thread.Sleep is a bad solution for this.  Can anyone recommend a better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bad solution are `Task`s here. `Task` should be used for short living operations, like asynch IO. If you want to control life time of task you should use `Thread` and sleep as much as you like, because `Thread` is individual, but `Task`s are rotated in thread pool which is shared.

Comment: You can specify TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, to create a new thread for the task instead using the ThreadPool.

Answer (score 2):

By my understanding, `Thread.Sleep` is bad generally, because it force-shifts everything out of memory even when that's not necessary.  It won't be a big deal in most cases, but it could be a performance issue.

I'm in the habit of using this snippet instead:

```
new System.Threading.EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset).WaitOne(1000);
```

Fits on one line, and isn't overly complicated -- it creates an event handle that will never be set, and then waits for the full timeout period before continuing.

Anyway, if you're just trying to have something repeat every 5 minutes, a better approach would probably be to use a Timer.  You could even make a class to neatly wrap everything if your repeated work methods are already factored out:

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
public class WorkRepeater
{
    Timer m_Timer;

    WorkRepeater(Action workToRepeat, TimeSpan interval)
    {
        m_Timer = new System.Timers.Timer((double)Interval.Milliseconds);
        m_Timer.Elapsed += 
            new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler((o, ea) => WorkToRepeat());
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        m_Timer.Start();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        m_Timer.Stop();
    }
}
```